# EasyPHP DevServer and PHP include

Tags: php, apache, easyphp

I'm using the last version of EasyPHP DevServer. I have a new working directory called "myproject" that contains several php files (index.php included). Some php files use the function

```
<?include("_afile.php");?>
```

These file seem not be called from the include. I have tried to change the php.ini files with the absolute path of the included files but nothing seems to be changed. What I'm missing ?
Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I should activate short_open_tag in php.ini.